# Writing mongoDb queries using mongoose to create node api

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some mongoDb collections 'classrooms' and 'students' of the form:
Classrooms:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c7219dbd5f92cd78ae4b7e"), 
    "name" : "My Students", 
    "user" : ObjectId("56c7218cbd5f92cd78ae4b7c"), 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-19T14:07:25.965+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-19T14:07:25.965+0000"), 
    "students" : [
        ObjectId("56dbb26cff34aa686c0d9d25"), 
        ObjectId("56f7c2bf1982aa9219ae8843")
    ], 
    "role" : "user", 
    "allowDelete" : false, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Students:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56dbb26cff34aa686c0d9d25"), 
    "email" : "1989manjari@gmail.com", 
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("56c7218cbd5f92cd78ae4b7c"), 
    "classRoom" : ObjectId("56c7219dbd5f92cd78ae4b7e"), 
    "mentorEmail" : "gauravatbits@gmail.com", 
    "studentId" : ObjectId("56ced54303b7cb7b0eda9862"), 
    "status" : true, 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-03-11T15:32:36.806+0000"), 
    "autoAdd" : true, 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-06T04:30:36.073+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

My query is:

```
id_list = db.classrooms.distinct("students");
db.students.find({_id: {$in: id_list}, studentId:{$exists:false}},{email:1, mentorEmail: 1}).pretty()
```

Now I want to create an endpoint in node api for this response. So i wanted to know how can I write these queries in Mongoose and create endpoint like: app.get('/api/myquery') to get the json result.

P.S. : Is it possible to do this, without creating schema in Mongoose because i also have some collections which have large no. of fields(38 fields). I just want to get some json data by applying queries in already existing collections.

Answer (score 0):

something like this with mongoose

just pseudo code

```
var model = mongoose.model("collection", mongooseSchema)

app.get('/api/myquery', function(){
    model.find({_id : id_list}, "email mentorEmail", function(err, data){
       if(err)throw err;
       res.json(data) // maybe use JSON.stringify() if didnt get json but that sets application/json in header of HTTP
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly insert jsons in mongoose but you should keep in mind that only that data will be read which are mentioned in the models in mongoose. Do keeping 38 fields is not a problem just insert in directly.